# Listview with radio buttons in flutter slows performance

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to update when the value of radio button changes in flutter But its slowing down the app.

I have created the following listview with the radio buttons yes and no

```
          final List<ItemModel> _questions =
                   List.generate(100, (index) => ItemModel(name: 'nm_$index', id: index + 1, checked: ''));


            ListTile(
                title: Text((index + 1).toString() + ". " + question.name),
                subtitle: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _questions[index].checked = 'yes';
                        });
                      },
                      title: const Text("Yes"),
                      leading: Radio(
                          value: 'yes',
                          groupValue: question.checked,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              _questions[index].checked = 'yes';
                            });
                          }),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: const Text("No"),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _questions[index].checked = 'no';
                        });
                      },
                      leading: Radio(
                          value: 'no',
                          groupValue: question.checked,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              _questions[index].checked = 'no';
                            });
                          }),
                    )
                  ],
                ));
```

The above listview has two radio buttons where each row is either marked as yes or no. It works well for a small list but when the list gets larger like the above with 100 items the app starts to slow down. I believe its caused by the calling of setState on each radio button click which then causes the ui to be rebuilt.

Is there a way i can update the status of the selected radio without causing the ui to rebuild or is there a way i can improve the above to make the app stop lagging and slowing down when there is alot of items.

Comment: Use a `ListView.builder` so items are drawn lazily. And you could also move the logic to a changeNotifier if the performance is still sub par. That way you could have more control about what rebuilds.